# ReactJS - Uncaught ReferenceError: function is not defined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, this, bind

I am new to reactJs and I am having an issue with undefined function.

As I see I define it at my constructor, but..

bundle.js:758 Uncaught ReferenceError: myCallback is not defined.

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import Vivus from "vivus";

export default class MySkills extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = {visable: false};
        this.onScroll = this.onScroll.bind(this);
        this.myCallback = this.myCallback.bind(this);
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
    }

    myCallback() {
       alert("myCallback");
    }

    onScroll() {
        var scrollY = window.scrollY;
        if (scrollY > 2300 && this.state.visable === false) {
            new Vivus("foo", {duration: 100, file: 'bar'}, myCallback.bind(this));
    }
}
```

Maybe somebody can explain better the binding of functions? It seems to be working with the onScrool function, but the myCallback function is not working.

Thank You!

Answer (score 2):

You have the binding in your constructor (which I don't recommend) so you can just write change this

```
new Vivus("foo", {duration: 100, file: 'bar'}, myCallback.bind(this));
```

to this

```
new Vivus("foo", {duration: 100, file: 'bar'}, this.myCallback);
```

Or you can skip the bindings in the constructor and use this

```
new Vivus("foo", {duration: 100, file: 'bar'}, this.myCallback.bind(this));
```

Or you can skip the bindings in the constructor and use an arrow function (my personal recommendation)

```
new Vivus("foo", {duration: 100, file: 'bar'}, ()=> myCallback())
```

If the callback needs to accept an argument

```
new Vivus("foo", {duration: 100, file: 'bar'}, x=> myCallback(x))
```

Or if the callback needs to accept a variable number of arguments

```
new Vivus("foo", {duration: 100, file: 'bar'}, (...args)=> myCallback(...args))
```

Is that enough options?

**^_^**

---

Likewise, I'd recommend removing the binding for `this.onScroll` in the constructor and where you have this

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', this.onScroll);
}
```

Use this instead

```
componentDidMount() {
  document.addEventListener('scroll', event=> this.onScroll(event));
}
```